# Insert tipo timestamp em banco de dados firebird

Tags: firebird, timestamp

Erro no `insert` em banco de dados firebird, field `DataCadastro` de tipo `timestamp` não aceita `string`.

```
INSERT INTO VENDA(CODIGO, NRO_VENDA, DATA_VENDA, VALOR_TOTAL_PRODUTOS, VALOR_ACRESCIMO,
VALOR_DESCONTO, VALOR_TOTAL_VENDA, CODIGO_CLIENTE)
VALUES (1, 1, '14/12/2016', 5, 2, 3, 2, 1)
```

> Overflow occurred during data type conversion.

Comment: O formato da data deve ser MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente substituir a data de `'14/12/2016'`por `'12/14/2016'`

A data no firebird segue o seguinte formato: `MM/DD/YYYY`.